# Gatsby JS Uncaught TypeError React Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, graphql, gatsby

I used React Google Maps api in one of my Gatsby sites. I created the following component and imported it into one of my pages. Here is the code for the compenent.

```
import React, { useState } from "react"
import {
  GoogleMap,
  useLoadScript,
  Marker,
  InfoWindow,
} from "@react-google-maps/api"
import { useStaticQuery, graphql } from "gatsby"
import mapStyles from "./mapStyles"

const Indianapolis = {
  lat: 39.768402,
  lng: -86.158066,
}

const mapContainerStyle = {
  height: "100%",
  width: "100%",
}
const options = {
  styles: mapStyles,
  disableDefaultUI: true,
  zoomControl: true,
}

const Map = () => {
  const data = useStaticQuery(graphql`
    {
      allKmlPoint {
        edges {
          node {
            properties {
              name
              Longitude
              Latitude
              FRP_Project_Numbers
              description
              styleUrl
              styleHash
            }
            id
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `)

  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(null)

  const frpLocation = data.allKmlPoint.edges

  //console.log(process.env.GATSBY_GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY)
  const { isLoaded, loadError } = useLoadScript({
    googleMapsApiKey: process.env.GATSBY_GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY,
  })
  const mapRef = React.useRef()
  const onMapLoad = React.useCallback(map => {
    mapRef.current = map
    console.log(map)
  }, [])

  const onUnmount = React.useCallback(function callback(map) {
    console.log(map)
  }, [])

  if (loadError) return "Error"
  if (!isLoaded) {
    return "Loading..."
  }

  //console.log("comes here")
  return (
    <div className="map-container">
      <span className="top-text">Project</span>
      <span className="horizontal-line"></span>
      <span className="bottom-text">
        Locati<span className="full-color">o</span>ns
      </span>
      <span className="map-blurb">
        FRP has a project portfolio across a wide geographic region. Click the
        Map to Zoom and pan to the project locations for various market types.
      </span>
      <div className="map-wrapper">
        <GoogleMap
          zoom={8}
          center={Indianapolis}
          mapContainerStyle={mapContainerStyle}
          options={options}
          onUnmount={onUnmount}
          onLoad={onMapLoad}
        >
          {frpLocation.map(marker => (
            <Marker
              key={marker.node.id}
              position={{
                lat: parseFloat(marker.node.properties.Latitude),
                lng: parseFloat(marker.node.properties.Longitude),
              }}
              icon={{
                url: `icon_${marker.node.properties.styleUrl.slice(-6)}.svg`,
                origin: new window.google.maps.Point(0, 0),
                anchor: new window.google.maps.Point(15, 15),
                scaledSize: new window.google.maps.Size(30, 30),
              }}
              onClick={() => {
                setSelected(marker)
              }}
            />
          ))}

          {selected ? (
            <InfoWindow
              position={{
                lat: parseFloat(selected.node.properties.Latitude),
                lng: parseFloat(selected.node.properties.Longitude),
              }}
              onCloseClick={() => {
                setSelected(null)
              }}
            >
              <div>
                <p>{selected.node.properties.name}</p>
              </div>



            </InfoWindow>
          ) : null}
        </GoogleMap>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
export default Map
```

The page works just fine. However, when I try to move away from the page (which has the google map) to another page (in Gatsby), the page transition is not smooth. Gatsby reloads the new page entirely. The console gives me the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: a is undefined
    ZU marker.js:48
    <anonymous> marker.js:45
    setTimeout handler*_.bn common.js:17
    <anonymous> marker.js:45
    H js:207
    trigger js:204
    remove js:207
    removeListener js:203
    unregisterEvent reactgooglemapsapi.esm.js:142
    unregisterEvents reactgooglemapsapi.esm.js:150
    componentWillUnmount reactgooglemapsapi.esm.js:2118
    wrappedMethod react-hot-loader.development.js:707
    React 27
    unlisten index.js:103
    unlisten index.js:101
    promise callback*componentDidMount/refs.unlisten< index.js:99
    navigate history.js:100
    navigate history.js:99
    navigate navigation.js:120
    promise callback*navigate navigation.js:84
    ___navigate navigation.js:162
    onClick index.js:256
    onClick index.js:477
    React 22
marker.js:48:38
```

There are several instances of this error on the console (I think as many as the number of markers I have on my map).

I am sure it is a simple fix to get rid of this error. Can someone help

UPDATE:Based on what @Ferran said, I used the following code, Still does not work:

I created a useState hook as you said.

```
const [frpMap, setFrpMap] = useState(null)
mapRef.current = map
...
const onLoad = React.useCallback(function callback(map) {
    setFrpMap(map)  
  }, [])

const onUnmount = React.useCallback(function callback(map) {
    setFrpMap(null)
    mapRef.current = null
    //console.log(map)
  }, [])
```

I think I am not sure how to use the map variable set in the setFrpMap hook to render the GoogleMap.

So, when I do setFrpMap(null) on unmount nothing really happens.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
const onUnmount = React.useCallback(function callback(map) {
    map.data = null
  }, [])
```

did the trick

Answer (score 0):

You aren't unmounting your map so it breaks when the routing changes. This is not doing anything:

```
  const onUnmount = React.useCallback(function callback(map) {
    console.log(map)
  }, [])
```

I would suggest an approach using `useState` hook, in order to mount and unmount/dispose the map when needed:

```
import React, { useState } from "react"
import {
  GoogleMap,
  useLoadScript,
  Marker,
  InfoWindow,
} from "@react-google-maps/api"
import { useStaticQuery, graphql } from "gatsby"
import mapStyles from "./mapStyles"

const Indianapolis = {
  lat: 39.768402,
  lng: -86.158066,
}

const mapContainerStyle = {
  height: "100%",
  width: "100%",
}
const options = {
  styles: mapStyles,
  disableDefaultUI: true,
  zoomControl: true,
}

const Map = () => {
  const [map, setMap] = React.useState(null)

  const data = useStaticQuery(graphql`
    {
      allKmlPoint {
        edges {
          node {
            properties {
              name
              Longitude
              Latitude
              FRP_Project_Numbers
              description
              styleUrl
              styleHash
            }
            id
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `)

  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(null)

  const frpLocation = data.allKmlPoint.edges

  //console.log(process.env.GATSBY_GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY)
  const { isLoaded, loadError } = useLoadScript({
    googleMapsApiKey: process.env.GATSBY_GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY,
  })
  const mapRef = React.useRef()
  const onMapLoad = React.useCallback(map => {
    mapRef.current = map
    setMap(map)
    console.log(map)
  }, [])

  const onUnmount = React.useCallback(function callback(map) {
    console.log(map)
    setMap(null)
  }, [])

  if (loadError) return "Error"
  if (!isLoaded) {
    return "Loading..."
  }

  //console.log("comes here")
  return (
    <div className="map-container">
      <span className="top-text">Project</span>
      <span className="horizontal-line"></span>
      <span className="bottom-text">
        Locati<span className="full-color">o</span>ns
      </span>
      <span className="map-blurb">
        FRP has a project portfolio across a wide geographic region. Click the
        Map to Zoom and pan to the project locations for various market types.
      </span>
      <div className="map-wrapper">
        <GoogleMap
          zoom={8}
          center={Indianapolis}
          mapContainerStyle={mapContainerStyle}
          options={options}
          onUnmount={onUnmount}
          onLoad={onMapLoad}
        >
          {frpLocation.map(marker => (
            <Marker
              key={marker.node.id}
              position={{
                lat: parseFloat(marker.node.properties.Latitude),
                lng: parseFloat(marker.node.properties.Longitude),
              }}
              icon={{
                url: `icon_${marker.node.properties.styleUrl.slice(-6)}.svg`,
                origin: new window.google.maps.Point(0, 0),
                anchor: new window.google.maps.Point(15, 15),
                scaledSize: new window.google.maps.Size(30, 30),
              }}
              onClick={() => {
                setSelected(marker)
              }}
            />
          ))}

          {selected ? (
            <InfoWindow
              position={{
                lat: parseFloat(selected.node.properties.Latitude),
                lng: parseFloat(selected.node.properties.Longitude),
              }}
              onCloseClick={() => {
                setSelected(null)
              }}
            >
              <div>
                <p>{selected.node.properties.name}</p>
              </div>



            </InfoWindow>
          ) : null}
        </GoogleMap>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
export default Map
```

The idea is to initially set as `null` your map and set it in your `onLoad` function with:

```
  const onMapLoad = React.useCallback(map => {
    mapRef.current = map
    setMap(map)
    console.log(map)
  }, [])
```

*Note: adapt the snippet to your needs.*

Since the callback is receiving the map as a parameter, you are able to use it along with `useState` hook.

On the other hand, use the opposite way when unmounting the map (`onUnmount`):

```
  const onUnmount = React.useCallback(function callback(map) {
    console.log(map)
    setMap(null) // alternatively use map.data=null
   
  }, [])
```

The same approach, your callback is receiving the map though you don't need it so, you can set the map object as `null`.

You can check the [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-google-maps/api) for further details.

Comment: What you say makes a lot of sense.

I created a useState hook as you said.

`code`
const [frpMap, setFrpMap] = useState(null)
mapRef.current = map
...
const onLoad = React.useCallback(function callback(map) {
    setFrpMap(map)  
  }, [])

const onUnmount = React.useCallback(function callback(map) {
    setFrpMap(null)
    mapRef.current = null
    //console.log(map)
  }, [])
`code`

I think I am not sure how to use the map variable set in the setFrpMap hook to render the GoogleMap.

So, when I do setFrpMap(null) on unmount nothing really happens.

Comment: Can you update your initial question? It's impossible to read code like this.